# how to have match multiple relationships in cypher

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

Cypher  has  got  support  for  OR(|)  in  match  relationship
I  want something  like this
Cypher  query= ' start n= node:node_auto_index(name=ashish '')   MATCH
n-[?: f&:t]-> k   return  k
'

Cypher  supports   this  one
n-[?:f|:t]->k
for  2  relation  its  like  this
G -[:f]->k <-[:t]-H
But  what  about   mote  than  2  relationships?
Say  3,4  etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could seperate a couple of match statements like this:

```
MATCH n-[:A_REL_TYPE*]-end, n-[:ANOTHER_REL_TYPE*]-end
```

Answer (score 4):

You just list them as separate MATCH elements

```
start n=node:node_auto_index(name='ashish') 
MATCH n-[:f]-> k, n-[:t]-> k, n-[:g]-> k
return k
```